# Load Excel file to R while setting column equal to a factor

Tags: r

I have an Excel file that I am trying to load into R using the odbcConnectExcel and sqlQuery commands from RODBC package. One of the columns has numerical values with plus or minus signs, such as '5+ or '3-. However, if i do something like,

```
conn <- odbcConnectExcel("file.xls")
sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`")
```

then the column with the plus and minus signs will be returned as a numerical column with those symbols stripped. Is there a way to have this column read in as a factor in which the signs are maintained? I would prefer to not have to convert the file to another format first.

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but you might try something like: "SELECT col1 & '' FROM `Sheet1$`"...in other words, try to cast the column in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data like this becomes a factor if you use the xlsReadWrite (http://www.swissr.org/software/xlsreadwrite) package to read the file:

```
library(xlsReadWrite)
x <- read.xls(file="file.xls")
```

However, note that you need to do something more than just `install.packages("xlsReadWrite")` to get this package to run. You need another file or so, I forgot.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly address your question, but hopefully it will help:

This is the best summary of options for connecting to Excel that I have seen: [Export Data Frames To Multi-worksheet Excel File](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/export-data-frames-to-multi-worksheet-excel-file/).  While it deals generally with exporting, importing is also possible with most of these approaches.

My favorite is actually the [RDCOMClient](http://www.omegahat.org/RDCOMClient/) because it provides total control over Excel as an application.